# I am getting connection reset error when trying execute two queries at the same time in arangodb?

Tags: node.js, arangodb, connection-reset, arangojs

I am using `arangojs v6.14.1` and `arangodb version 3.6.4.`. I also have the `nodejs` express app which is intended to serve client requests.

I am experiencing an issue while executing concurrent requests. The database connection hangup when I concurrently process client requests:

What the app will do when it receives a request?

Open a database connection -

```
db = new Database(dbConfig.url); 
db.useDatabase(dbConfig.name); 
db.useBasicAuth(dbConfig.username, dbConfig.password);
```

There are multiple middleware functions that need to access to perform various functions and accessibility checks. And for each middleware I tried to

- open a new database connection ->
- perform the action ->
- close the connection ->
- return the result to next middleware.

This works fine with single request at a time. But if I tried to call two APIs at same time, I am getting CONNECTIONRESET error. And also throwing socket hangup error.

I tried to commend out the close connection method and it started working fine for a while. But when I increased the number of connections, it again showing the same error as "CONNECTIONRESET".

I have searched the documentation of `arangojs` regarding the connection manipulation. But I haven't found any information regarding the same.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late for you, but I had a similar issue.  After talking with ArangoDB support, it turned out to be an issue with sockets.

Looking at the output from `netstat -aplnt` I was seeing a lot of `CLOSE_WAIT` and `TIME_WAIT` messages, indicating that there were A LOT of connections that were not being closed properly.

The solution was to enable persistent connections (see [arangojs config](https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/7.5.0/modules/_connection_.html#config) for keep-alive and maxSockets) and then re-using a single connection whenever possible.  This was more than just a settings change, requiring some code modifications as well.